# Get posts from private telegram channel

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to resend posts from private channel in Telegram to my account, but I can't add bot as administrator to this channel, because I'm not an administrator. As far as I know telegram api can't help with this task, so I think best way to achieve it is to parse posts from page sources in browser using JS.
Can you please help with ideas how to write such bot in js or any other ideas to solve this task ?

Comment: What do you want to do? Why not just contact channel owner?

Comment: @Sean can't do that just because admins don't agree

Comment: So why you want to do things that admins don't let you do? :)